# Filtering objects by timezone aware dates

Tags: django, python-3.x

Let's say I have TIME_ZONE variable in settings set to 'Europe/Prague' and also USE_TZ set to True. I also have some data stored in Example:

```
   id  timestamp
   1   2012-07-27T00:00:00+02:00
   2   2018-03-11T02:00:00+01:00
   3   2013-11-04T14:08:40+01:00
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Extract all dates from those data
2. Filter those data date by date and perform some other action on them

For extracting dates I use either `Example.dates('timestamp', 'day')` or `Example.annotate(date=TruncDay('timestamp')).values('date')`.

Now here is the difference: for first object from example above (with `timestamp=2012-07-27T00:00:00+02:00`), date returned by first approach is `2012-07-27`, whereas for second approach it is `2012-07-26`.

I would like filter to be timezone aware, so I'm currently sticking with the first one.

For filtering I am using `Example.filter(timestamp__date=date)`. And there's a problem - it seems that `__date` filters by date converted to UTC. For date `2012-07-27` it returns empty QuerySet and for `2012-07-26` it returns first object.

Is there any way to achieve filtering by timezone aware date?

Comment: With `USE_TZ` set to `True`, all your datetimes in the database should be in `UTC`, which is not what you're showing. Is this data that was created outside of Django? What database are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong -  it seems that in the database data are stored without timezone. I use an unmanaged model with legacy PostgreSQL database, so these data were created outside of Django.

Output of `Example.objects.values('timestamp')` is someting like `<QuerySet [{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 17, 0, 0)}]>`, whereas for: `Example.objects.annotate(date=TruncDay('timestamp')).values('date')` it is 
`<QuerySet [{'date': datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 16, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Prague' CET+1:00:00 STD>)}]>`.

Comment: I think you first need to deal with the bigger issue of the inconsistency in the way timezones are stored. You say that you want the filter (and therefore data) to be timezone aware, but that information will be stripped out for all new data values due to the semantics of `USE_TZ = True`. So you're better off converting all existing data to `UTC` (and storing the timezone separately, if you want), or switching to `USE_TZ = False`.